Trying to solve a factory game with systems of linear equations
First, some context. I'm a huge fan of factory games like Factorio, Satisfactory, and Minecraft with tech mods. This has caused me to run up against the wall of "I have some input and I want to know just how much I can output" and it always seems to come to me guessing how much I can make of a particular item, multiplying that out until a number in the chain doesn't match my constraints, re-guessing, and repeating. What I would like to do is set up some form of script or concrete math to solve these problems easier without guessing.
I had the explanation of systems of linear equations taught to me as,
A factory produces 2 products, A and B. A requires 2h of labor and 1 unit of material and sells for 30, B requires 1h of labor and 2 units of material and sells for 40. The factory has 100h of labor and 80 units of material.
let $P$ represent the maximum profit $P = 30x + 40y$
Labor: $2x + y <= 100$
Material: $x + 2y <= 80$
This can then be solved with the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
100 \\
80\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assuming that is correct, I'm trying to understand how I would go about making a similar equation where I have multiple dependencies. To take an example from a game I've been playing recently.
In Satisfactory, I have the set of recipes (all recipes are given in the form of resources per minute):

30 Iron Ore -> 30 Iron Ingots
30 Iron Ingots -> 20 Iron Plates
15 Iron Ingots -> 15 Iron Rods
10 Iron Rods -> 40 Screws
30 Iron Plates + 60 Screws -> 5 Reinforced Iron Plates

Given the input of 120 Iron Ore per minute, how would I maximize the amount of Reinforced Iron Plates?
My first instinct is to turn this into some form of matrix where each recipe is represented as a row, and each type of input is a column, but then my restraint vector becomes dependent on the solution.
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{30}{30} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{30}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{15}{15} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{10}{40} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{30}{5} & 0 & \frac{60}{5}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
120\\
?\\
?\\
?\\
?\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is there a better way to go about this type of maximization problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Related: https://github.com/R-O-C-K-E-T/Factorio-SAT

This is an example of a linear programming problem, and the simplex method (which involves these matrix equations but requires a bit more setup and somewhat different execution) is the mathematical process that solves such problems. (I've linked to the Wikipedia pages, but I'm sure there are better tutorials out there.)

I've found this website helpful for learning to perform the simplex method: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Applied_Mathematics/Applied_Finite_Mathematics_(Sekhon_and_Bloom)/04%3A_Linear_Programming_The_Simplex_Method/4.02%3A_Maximization_By_The_Simplex_Method

For anyone like myself that prefers a short video with a visual explanation, I knew that "simplex method" sounded familiar as I had watched this in the past and completely slipped my mind on the power of it. The art of Linear Programming
